# CodeIgniter Ion auth customize

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to make an app. I'm using Ion Auth for it.

What I mean is I want to make use of the library.

Current structure of the app:

1. Posts -ID(pk), Title, Desc,
   post_author, post_date
2. Comments
   -Comment_id(pk), Comment_post_id, comment_author, comment_content
3. Backend

Let's say my name is Lisa, Lisa submit a post. It uses the current login and save it to Posts table. It should save Id or name? I do not know how to integrate it with my program.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to check out my standard CI project on github to get an idea of how to use it since it sounds like you're fairly new to this.

http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Standard-Project

Good luck with your project.

Comment: I've downloaded your CI standard project. Im still blur.

I'm working on a CRUD controller/post with your ION auth.

eg: like facebook. each user has wall. they can post anything and other user can comment on that post.